# How to make automapper case insensitive?

Tags: automapper

I'm using automapper v1.1 to map IDataReader to Dto. Seems it is doing case sensitive mapping. How can I config it to do case insensitive mapping? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found this: http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/6127